# Windows phone app, WebBrowser, iframe and google maps not working together

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-maps, iframe, windows-phone-7.1

I am having a problem with iframe and WebBrowser. In my app I have a page with WebBrowser which goes to specific url and should show a google map (embedded with iframe). However, it does not. Getting the error *"This content cannot be displayed in a frame.   To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."*

But if I go to this url with the emulators browser everything works fine, same with ie in my pc. I also tested with other urls which dont have iframes and the WebBrowser works fine. I have also tried webBrowser.NavigateToString with the same code the url has but doesnt work either. I do have the &output=embed at the end of the map url in iframe. Also tried using my api key in the html.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im gonna answer to myself. 
Adding this line in c#

```
webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
```

and this in xaml

```
IsScriptEnabled="True"
```

did the trick. 
So scripting is disabled in WebBrowser control by default.
Well, now I know.

Found the answer from here: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/18/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-18-webbrowser-control/